# Why certain external REST API's could not be consumed from Genexus .Net?

Tags: genexus

I'm using GX16 U7 with .Net Generator trying to consume the following rest API:

```
&httpclient.Secure= 1 
&httpclient.Host = "api-uat.kushkipagos.com" 
&httpclient.BaseUrl = "/transfer-subscriptions/v1/"
&httpclient.AddHeader('public-merchant-id',"f3f59379695b4200b0a84936e2a922e7")  
&httpclient.Execute('GET','bankList') 
&mensajecharacter = &httpclient.ToString()
```

But no response is returned, only Status code 0 is what I get.

I'm using .Net Framework 4. On my Web.Config I have the following configuration:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

The same code works fine on a Visual Studio Console Application using RestSharp library:

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://api-uat.kushkipagos.com/transfer-subscriptions/v1/bankList");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("public-merchant-id", "102ee07c8eda4c31b229c78a9f03cbab");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Is there another way to do it on Genexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with Upgrade 9 and it is working as expected.

Here you have the [LIVE URL](https://apps5.genexus.com/Idc9ee0e1243ee0a5d35c817660f4a7fde/testws.aspx). Are you able to test with [Upgrade 9](https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/downloadcenter?data=5885;;)?

Comment: Great! It works. The problem was that my test program is a command line procedure not a web panel. On web panels, configuration is taken from web.config where I tell to use Framework 4.6   `<system.web><httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.6" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" /></system.web>`